# Defining the exponential and logarithm functions

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

As the title says, I'm wondering what is the "correct" (or maybe "most logically consistent") way to define the logarithm and exponential functions, $\ln(x)$ and $e^x$.

It seems that in every course I take, these things are defined differently, or in a different order. The first time they were treated with any modicum of rigour for me, we proved that the sequence $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ converges, and defined its limit to be the number $e$.

Later when we discussed series, we saw that the power series $\frac{x^k}{k!}$ converges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and defined it to be $e^x$, calling it the exponential function.

Using this definition, is it easy to show that the exponential evaluated at $1$ is the aforementioned number, $e$, as the notation suggests?

In this first class, we never even mentioned the logarithm. I've read some books which first define the logarithm and then show it must be invertible, defining the exponential to be this inverse.

I think there are also some different definitions of these functions involving limits.

Why are there so many ways of introducing these concepts, and which one would you say is the best?

Comment: It's not too bad. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Equivalence_of_characterizations_1_and_2).

Comment: This is as useful as asking what is the correct order between theorem and corollary when considering the inverse and implicit function theorem. Some topics have a degree of interconnectedness that defies any attempts at canonical serializations.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to define $e^x$ as the only solution of the ODE
$$ f-f' = 0$$
under the constraint $f(0)=1$, then define the natural logarithm as the inverse function. More or less, this is the same as defining $e^x$ as the only (locally bounded or) continuous solution of the functional equation
$$ f(x)\,f(y)=f(x+y) $$
under the constraint $f(1)=e$.